# org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecutionException: Partition handler returned an unsuccessful step in Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am using Spring Batch using Spring Boot. In this example, I've implemented the Custom Partition since Employee Table has UUID value as a PK.

```
Error:
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30002ms.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:307) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400) ~[spring-tx-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373) ~[spring-tx-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy74.getTransaction(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:273) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:258) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:208) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:138) [spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:135) [spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30002ms.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:689) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:196) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:161) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:128) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:263) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 25 common frames omitted

2020-05-16 20:55:22.675  INFO 31056 --- [cTaskExecutor-7] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step: [slaveStep:Thread--9] executed in 32s370ms
###################### 80
2020-05-16 20:55:22.787  INFO 31056 --- [TaskExecutor-10] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:70}] to localhost:27017
2020-05-16 20:55:22.815  INFO 31056 --- [TaskExecutor-10] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step: [slaveStep:Thread--8] executed in 32s510ms
###################### 50
###################### 70
2020-05-16 20:55:22.839  INFO 31056 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step: [slaveStep:Thread--5] executed in 32s539ms
###################### 20
###################### 40
2020-05-16 20:55:22.845  INFO 31056 --- [cTaskExecutor-4] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step: [slaveStep:Thread--7] executed in 32s540ms
###################### 10
2020-05-16 20:55:22.851  INFO 31056 --- [cTaskExecutor-9] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step: [slaveStep:Thread--2] executed in 32s546ms
###################### 30
2020-05-16 20:55:22.856  INFO 31056 --- [cTaskExecutor-3] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step: [slaveStep:Thread--1] executed in 32s556ms
###################### 100
###################### 60
2020-05-16 20:55:22.860  INFO 31056 --- [cTaskExecutor-6] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:3, serverValue:71}] to localhost:27017
2020-05-16 20:55:22.864  INFO 31056 --- [cTaskExecutor-5] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step: [slaveStep:Thread--3] executed in 32s559ms
2020-05-16 20:55:22.867  INFO 31056 --- [cTaskExecutor-6] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step: [slaveStep:Thread--4] executed in 32s565ms
2020-05-16 20:55:22.874  INFO 31056 --- [cTaskExecutor-8] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step: [slaveStep:Thread--6] executed in 32s569ms
2020-05-16 20:55:22.883  INFO 31056 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step: [slaveStep:Thread--10] executed in 32s583ms
2020-05-16 20:55:22.885 ERROR 31056 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Encountered an error executing step contactStepOne in job readContactJob

org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecutionException: Partition handler returned an unsuccessful step
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.PartitionStep.doExecute(PartitionStep.java:112) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:208) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148) [spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:410) [spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:136) [spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:319) [spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:147) [spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) [spring-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:140) [spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) [spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) [spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) [spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) [spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) [spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy71.run(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at com.example.PostgresMongoContactsMigrationApplication.run(PostgresMongoContactsMigrationApplication.java:49) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:784) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:768) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.example.PostgresMongoContactsMigrationApplication.main(PostgresMongoContactsMigrationApplication.java:38) [classes/:na]
```

EmployeePartitions.java

```
public class EmployeePartitions implements Partitioner {

    @Override
    public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize) {
        Map<String, ExecutionContext> partitionMap = new HashMap<>();

        int limit = 10;
        int offset = 0;
        int increment = 10;
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i += increment) {
            counter++;
            if (i == 0)
                offset = i;
            else
                offset = i + 1;
            limit = i + increment;

            System.out.println("OFFSET " + offset + ", LIMIT = " + limit);

            ExecutionContext context = new ExecutionContext();
            context.put("limit", limit);
            context.put("offset", offset);

            partitionMap.put("Thread--" + counter, context);
            System.out.println(partitionMap);
        }

        System.out.println(partitionMap.size());
        return partitionMap;
    }
}
```

EmployeeJob.java

```
@Configuration
public class EmployeeJob {
    private static final Integer chunkSize = 200;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public EmployeesPartitions EmployeesPartition() {
        return new EmployeesPartitions();
    }


    @Bean("readEmployeeJob")
    public Job readEmployeeJob() throws Exception {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("readEmployeeJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(EmployeeStepOne())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step EmployeeStepOne() throws Exception {        
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("EmployeeStepOne")
                .partitioner(slaveStep().getName(), EmployeesPartition())
                .step(slaveStep())
                .gridSize(1)
                .taskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor())
                .build();
    }


    // slave step
    @Bean
    public Step slaveStep() throws Exception {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("slaveStep")
                .<EmployeesDTO, EmployeesDTO>chunk(chunkSize)
                .reader(EmployeeReader(null, null))
                .writer(EmployeeWriter())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "")
    @StepScope
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<EmployeesDTO> EmployeeReader(
            @Value("#{stepExecutionContext['limit']}") Long limit,
            @Value("#{stepExecutionContext['offset']}") Long offset) throws Exception {
        JdbcCursorItemReader<EmployeesDTO> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
        reader.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
        reader.setSql("select * from scv_owner.Employees order by Employee_id limit "+ limit +" offset "+offset);
        reader.setRowMapper(new EmployeeRowMapper());
        reader.afterPropertiesSet();
        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<EmployeesDTO, EmployeesDTO> EmployeeProcessor() {
        return new EmployeesProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<EmployeesDTO> EmployeeWriter() {
        return new EmployeeWriter();
    }
}
```

Comment: `Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; Connection is not available, request timed out after 30002ms.`. Looks like one of your partitions is not able to open a connection to the db, do you have enough connections in your pool? What is the size of your db connection pool? The connection timeout parameter is also important here because one of the partition can finish before the timeout and release its connection back to the pool which can be used by another partition.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine - I've not explicitly set the connection pool size, default its 10, what eould be the best size ? Also, I'm experincing the same issue when using multi-threded steps for other Job. What `connection timeout parameter` I would need to set ?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine - I am really stuck with n+1 issue of Spring Batch. Lets say, DB has 3 diffetent email object for single Employee (Email Table is different) and I would need to set that using Join, now the problem is where & how I will embed those 3 different email object into single employee?

Comment: Please keep focus on the issue discussed here, which is connection timeout. I added an answer for that.  For the question about emails, looks like you asked the question about the 3 emails issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61885183/5019386 (with user `user4567570`) which I answered as well.

Answer (score 0):

> what would be the best size ?

There is no best size, it depends on the use case. For maximum throughput, you should set the pool size such as each partition can have its own connection if you want maximum throughput, otherwise choose the timeout depending on how long a partition would take to finish.

For example, if you have 10 partitions and a pool size of 5, 5 partitions will be working and 5 others will be waiting. Now if a partition takes at most 1 minute to finish, the timeout could be set to 1 minute (or probably a bit longer) such that waiting partitions are not timed out, aka a connection is returned to the pool before the timeout.